# Triton into Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, triton, tritonserver

Having problems with implementing triton service into gitlab CI. As I noticed in the triton github https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server, they don't have any exposed port by default in Dockerfile and I'm not really able to access the service in any way? Is there any workaround for accessing the triton service?

Thanks!

```
.triton_service: &triton_service
  name: nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:21.06-py3
  command: ['tritonserver', '--model-repository=$(S3_TRITON_BUCKET)', '--model-control-mode=explicit', '--allow-http=true', '--allow-metrics=false', '--allow-gpu-metrics=false', '--log-verbose=true', '--log-info=true', '--log-warning=true', '--log-error=true']
  alias: triton
services:
  - *triton_service

script:
  - curl -v http://triton:8000/v2/health/ready
```

Comment: triton expose port 8000 for http and 8001 for grpc calls. have you checked in the logs that the models were loaded correctly and service is up?

Comment: Hey, yes, I know for sure triton was running correctly inside the image. Sadly I just had no way to access it bcs the Dockerfile had no exposing ports. + You are not able to expose any ports from gitlab-ci as well. The solution would be to store the triton image in your system and expose ports manually in Dockerfile everytime there is an update. I even asked them to expose the ports in Dockerfile but they refused.